# Desarrollando una APP Android 10 con Cordova, para MIUI 12.x, falla al prender 2 permisos (Candado y Pantallas emergent. 2º Plano)

Tags: android, cordova, programación-móvil, permisos, backgroundworker

Actualmente, estoy desarrollando una APP Android 10 con Cordova.

**Me funciona en otros teléfonos pero en MIUI de Xaomi NO.**

Tengo que activar dos permisos :

*1.- Bloque de aplicación (Candado). Quede siempre en Background.*

*2.- Permitir Mostrar ventanas emergentes mientras se ejecuta en segundo plano.*

Actualmente, estoy usando estos permisos:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ROLE_CALL_SCREENING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
```

Pero no logro encenderlos por programación los 2 permisos ya citados.

Agradeciendo la ayuda que me puedan prestar.

Atentamente.

Comment: Aporta más información , como tratas de encender esos permisos?

Comment: Los permisos son agregados al manifiesto dentro del config.xml . Sin embargo el permiso ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION no se activa y parece eque es necesario para MIUI de Xaomi. , intente con el pluing : <plugin name="cordova-plugin-open-overlay-permission" />   agregado al config.xml, pero me da error de compilacion.